# why system lack moveit_setup_assistant package

Tags: ros, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
when i use the command:

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

the warning information as followed:

```
[setup_assistant.launch] is neither a launch file in package [moveit_setup_assistant] nor is [moveit_setup_assistant] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

then i use `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, output the following infomation `/home/fhg/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`

the moveit has been installed in my unbuntu 14.04 64bit system

rospack find move +//fast double click tab key,then out put:

```
moveit_core                     moveit_planners_ompl            moveit_ros_manipulation         moveit_ros_planning             moveit_ros_visualization
moveit_fake_controller_manager  moveit_ros_benchmarks           moveit_ros_move_group           moveit_ros_planning_interface   moveit_ros_warehouse
moveit_msgs                     moveit_ros_benchmarks_gui       moveit_ros_perception           moveit_ros_robot_interaction    moveit_visual_tools
```

then i use rospack find command to check and find there are no moveit_setup_assistant package in my system.

So,i decided to install the package use the following command:

```
fhg@fhg-ThinkPad-T500:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 261 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.183 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2.975 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant amd64 0.6.0-0trusty-20150125-0937-+0000
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150125-0937-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

why installation failed.
what should i do

---

Edit:

then,i try to reinstall the moveit ,but fails

```
fhg@fhg-ThinkPad-T500:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  python-pyassimp ros-indigo-moveit-commander ros-indigo-moveit-planners
  ros-indigo-moveit-plugins ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant
  ros-indigo-moveit-simple-controller-manager
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pyassimp ros-indigo-moveit-commander ros-indigo-moveit-full
  ros-indigo-moveit-planners ros-indigo-moveit-plugins
  ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant
  ros-indigo-moveit-simple-controller-manager
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 261 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.362 kB/1.380 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.292 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-commander amd64 0.5.7-0trusty-20150125-0934-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-planners amd64 0.6.7-0trusty-20150125-1114-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-simple-controller-manager amd64 0.5.6-1trusty-20150121-0733-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-plugins amd64 0.5.6-1trusty-20150121-1025-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant amd64 0.6.0-0trusty-20150125-0937-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-moveit-full amd64 0.6.1-0trusty-20150125-1117-+0000
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-commander/ros-indigo-moveit-commander_0.5.7-0trusty-20150125-0934-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-planners/ros-indigo-moveit-planners_0.6.7-0trusty-20150125-1114-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-simple-controller-manager/ros-indigo-moveit-simple-controller-manager_0.5.6-1trusty-20150121-0733-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-plugins/ros-indigo-moveit-plugins_0.5.6-1trusty-20150121-1025-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150125-0937-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-full/ros-indigo-moveit-full_0.6.1-0trusty-20150125-1117-+0000_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

then,according to @gvdhoorn advices, use the followed command:

```
fhg@fhg-ThinkPad-T500:~$ wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb
--2015-03-29 21:31:43--  http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb
Resolving packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)... 64.50.236.52, 64.50.233.100
Connecting to packages.ros.org (packages.ros.org)|64.50.236.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1183802 (1,1M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb’

100%[==========================================================================================================>] 1.183.802    438KB/s   in 2,6s   

2015-03-29 21:31:47 (438 KB/s) - ‘ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb’ saved [1183802/1183802]
```

what should i do next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206137/why-system-lack-moveit_setup_assistant-package/) by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2015-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-28**:
Could be that your apt cache is out of date. Try a `sudo apt-get update`?

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-03-29**:
how to use the command
sudo apt-get update

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-29**:
Just run it in a terminal.

Also: please do not use *answers* to post *comments*, and update your original question with new information, instead of using answers for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-29**:
Are you behind a proxy? What is the output of

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant/ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb
```

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-03-29**:
@gvdhoom: i have used the command wget,the running result can be seen in updated question
what should i do next,thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-29**:
Well, have you done a `sudo apt-get update` already? Open a terminal, type `sudo apt-get update`, press `<enter>`. Watch for any errors. Now try again to run `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant`.

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-03-29**:
no ,i have not done the sudo apt-get update command

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-03-29**:
@gvdhoom , run sudo apt-get update, no errors occues

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-03-29**:
@gvdhoom,you are great powerful.
install successfully,what is the reason,why my question happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your error was probably caused by the fact that you had an out-of-date apt database, which caused `apt-get` to try and download *old versions* of the debians. Compare:

```
ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150308-0703-+0000_amd64.deb
```

with:

```
ros-indigo-moveit-setup-assistant_0.6.0-0trusty-20150125-0937-+0000_amd64.deb
```

The first file is a recent release (note the date: 2015-03-08), the second resulted in your `404` errors (again, date: 2015-01-25). The way the ROS package repository works is that older versions are *deleted*, so you cannot download them anymore. Trying to fetch old releases will cause HTTP `404` errors (as the files don't exist anymore).

By running `sudo apt-get update`, you update `apt`'s database, and it will then download the correct versions of files.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [manipulator](https://answers.ros.org/users/22010/manipulator/) on 2015-05-22**:
sorry i forgot mark it as correct